# Error in connecting components in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-proptypes

I get an error saying

> You must pass a component to the function returned by connect.
>   Instead received undefined.

I don't know why this is happening. It works with my `Checkout.js` component, but not my `Store.js` component. Why is it working for Checkout but not Store? I want to have access to `{total}` like I do in the Checkout component.

This is my container Store.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, getCurrency, getTotal} from '../ducks/cart';
import Store from '../components/Store';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
    total: getTotal(state, props)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Store);
```

And this is my component Store.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import Cart from '../containers/Cart';
import ProductList from '../containers/ProductList';
import Checkout from '../containers/Checkout';


class Store extends Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-12">

                  <h3>Armor and Weapon Store</h3>
                  <h4 className="badge badge-warning margin-right">Gold:  </h4>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8">
                  <ProductList />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                  <Cart />
                  <Checkout />
              </div>
          </div>


    </div>
    );
  }
}

Store.propTypes = {
    total: PropTypes.number,
}

export default Store;
```

Here is the container Checkout.js that works

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getItems, getCurrency, getTotal} from '../ducks/cart';
import Checkout from '../components/Checkout/Checkout';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
return {
    total: getTotal(state, props)
}
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Checkout);
```

And the component Checkout.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';
import Home from '../components/Home.js';

class Checkout extends Component{

buttonClick = () => {
  let { total } = this.props;
  var home = new Home
  var max = home.getMax()
    console.log(total);
    console.log(max);

    if (max >= total) {
      max = max - total;
        console.log(max);
      }
   else {
     console.log('Not enough gold!');
   }

   }
 render() {
  return(
    <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.buttonClick}> Checkout </button>
    </div>

   );
  }
}

Checkout.propTypes = {
total: PropTypes.number,
}

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: you container Checkout seems me wrong. Are you sure that code is the real code?

Comment: @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi I changed it to the right one now

Comment: Did you try put import Store from '../components/Store/Store' in the container Store?

Comment: Yes I did but the path is right. @HenriqueOeckslerBertoldi

Comment: @New2dis, can you check the components which you are importing into Store.js ?  `import Home from '../components/Home';
import Cart from '../containers/Cart';
import ProductList from '../containers/ProductList';
import Checkout from '../containers/Checkout';`